# How can I install git-annex assistant

Tags: installation, apt, ppa, git

I install recently `git annex` in ubuntu 12.10 using APT. However, the package seems to be built without the `assistant` support.

Is there a PPA or another way of installing it ? I'd rather avoid installing it from the tarball because I would like to install it in beginners computers (that I don't want to manage manually).

Does *raring ringtail* include the assistant support ?

Comment: There's a PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~fmarier/+archive/ppa), however it's just for Precise.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can use the installer if you install a newer ppa.

**Precise PPA**

https://launchpad.net/~fmarier/+archive/git-annex

A newer version of git-annex, including the assistant and WebApp. (Maintained by François Marier)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fmarier/git-annex
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-annex
```

see http://git-annex.branchable.com/install/Ubuntu/

Comment: Does it work with 12.10 or 13.04 ?

Comment: I get the error Failed to fetch 404. when I copy paste those into terminal.

Comment: Note, that the Precise PPA works on 13.04 as well - see http://wolfgangziegler.net/install-git-annex-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: This PPA only contains packages for 10.04 and 12.04 currently.

Comment: This PPA packages worked for me through 13.10 but no longer install on 14.04 ("Depends: libicu48 (>= 4.8-1) but it is not installable", plus a few "Recommends ... but it is not going to be installed")

Answer (score 1):

> Does raring ringtail include the assistant support ?

Yes, Ubuntu 13.04's [git-annex [image: Install git-annex]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/git-annex) package comes with the "assistant".

See the [changelog for the package](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/g/git-annex/git-annex_3.20121112ubuntu3/changelog), mentioning the assistant quite a few times. The changelog for 12.10 on the same package does not list those.

For working with older Ubuntu releases you'll need to find a Git backport PPA.